# How to use token generated at login time, for security, when user logs in a php web appliction from mobile application?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a PHP application in which user can login from mobile application and can do certain tasks. Mobile application works in the following way

1. User logs in from mobile application by sending email and password to PHP login page.
2. PHP login script validates the user and sends response back as success or failure.
3. If login succeeds, user can access other data by sending his customer id to php script and php script in turn sends response in xml format.

I want to make it more secure by using security token, which will be generated at login time and user has to send it to php script along with his customer id.

Where should I store the security token, and how can I match this with the token coming from the mobile app request?

Answer (score 0):

When device login with email & password, Generate a token, create a session for the user and store the token in session. for all further request from the device, that token has to be passed as header, so that you can validate it against the stored token.

Comment: Can we do this without using session?

Comment: Yes, you can manage your cookies manually by using `setcookie()` and `$_COOKIE`.  There is no need to go through the PHP's session mechanism.  You should consider whether you have a good reason for bypassing it and rolling your own, however.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called *session cookies*.  In web applications, they are typically implemented using *HTTP cookies*.  If you're using PHP, you can set it up to handle generating and tracking sessions for you and just use the [`$_SESSION` API](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).